# Problem with Drupal Beauty tips module

Tags: forms

I am using Beauty tips module to show AJAX content on hover, But When first time it loads I am getting unexpected look. From second time onward I get correct look.

I have attached an image of the problem.

The code that I am using for this is :

```
$options['bt_drupal_help_page'.$nodeid[$i]] = array(
  'cssSelect' => '#rating_'.$nodeid[$i],
  'ajaxPath' => $base_url.'/average_rating',
  'ajaxData' => array('rating'=>$nodeid[$i]),
 //'ajaxLoading' => '<blink>Wait Until It Loads...</blink>',
  'ajaxType' => 'GET',
  'width' => 'auto',
  'height' => '1000px',
  'ajaxCache' => false,
  //'windowMargin' => 5,   
   'cornerRadius' => 15,     
  //'cssClass' => 'tooltip-box',     
 //'cssStyles' => "padding: 2px",
 //'overlay' => true,
 'shrinkToFit' => false,
 'killTitle' => true,
 //'hoverIntentOpts' => '{interval:300,timeout:500}',
);

beautytips_add_beautytips($options);
```

Please let me know, whether I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like a problem with beautytips module, but instead a lack of styling that's causing the problem. You should be able to fix this with normal CSS.